# Right way to extend the EntityRepository in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, oop

During my first project with Symfony I needed a method to get a random item from an entity, so I created it inside my repository.

[image: random_item]

The method findRand just retrieves a random item from the group table.
[image: rand_method]

This method findRand is quite useful for my project so I would like to have something similar in every repository without creating it manually in each one.

Therefore, I would like to know what it's the proper way to extend the EntityRepository where the base methods of each repository are defined, like find, findAll, findBy, etc.

[image: EntityRepository]

Should I create something like this?

```
class BasicRepository extends EntityRepository
```

Edit:

I tried this:
[image: attempt]

But I get this error.

```
  The class 'App\Repository\GroupRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity
```

**Solution given by the user @will-b, which answers the question:**

"Since the /Repository directory is set to be a service prototype in Symfony by default, your BasicRepository should be declared as abstract class AbstractBasicRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository to prevent Symfony from registering it as a service and prevent doctrine from apply mapping. You should also refactor your AbstractBasicRepository::findRand() to utilize $table = $this->getClassMetadata()->getTableName(); instead of hard-coding or specifying it as an argument."

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If extending from a common repository sounds good for you, why not do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"right way"*? Is something not working for you by extending the EntityRepository? Alternatively you can use a [Trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to add the method to the repositories that you want to implement `::findRand()`. Another approach is to make a query service, that allows you to inject the service and call the method outside of the repository, since using `$em->getRepository()` is discouraged in favor of using dependency injection as `getRepository` is a service locator.

Comment: Hi guys, I have tried extending EntityRepository but it didn't work so I tried with  ServiceEntityRepository and it works but not as a method available for any Repository. I will try the trait approach as @WillB. suggest

Comment: The reason of my question is that I understand that just changing the Class EntityRepository in the vendor folder is a bad practice. I think there should be ways to extend this class in a more elegant way. I have been using Composer only for a month so I still lack a lot of basics.

Comment: Be sure to clear your cache after refactoring your entity repositories to `extends BasicRepository` instead of the original `EntityRepository` or `ServiceEntityRepository`. I find it odd that `ServiceEntityRepository` "works"... since it extends the `EntityRepository`

Comment: I have edited the question with the error I get @WillB.

Comment: You should also post your code as text instead of images.

Comment: Since the /Repository directory is set to be a service prototype in Symfony by default, your `BasicRepository` should be declared as `abstract class AbstractBasicRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository` to prevent Symfony from registering it as a service and prevent doctrine from apply mapping. You should also refactor your `AbstractBasicRepository::findRand()` to utilize `$table = $this->getClassMetadata()->getTableName();` instead of hard-coding or specifying it as an argument.

Comment: Omg thanks @WillB. ! It worked like a charm. Since the question is closed I will write the answer at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

For some time now, the [suggested way to create a custom repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository) has been as a service, extending a class from the DoctrineBundle - ServiceEntityRepository.

```
<?php
// see page on symfony.com for the list of 'use' statements
class ProductRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Product::class);
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that it's a service, and autowire-able, so when the class has been created it's immediately useable elsewhere, just by typehinting the fully-qualified name, if the services are setup as they would be by default in a Symfony application (or explicitly listed, if not).

This is also how the MakerBundle will create a default repository for an entity.

If this class is mentioned in the annotations/configuration of an entity class, it will also be the repository returned via the EntityManager's getRepository() - as you have already used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was probably not clear enough. I have added more details now. I want to have common methods between Repositories like findBy or findAll. I would like to have a findRand method that is available for any repository.